# Failed to fetch device property for senderID (778835616971358209) use primary keyboard info instead

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uikit, textfield

The textField I put on the MapView
" Failed to fetch device property for senderID (778835616971358209) use primary keyboard info instead. " gives this error when trying to open the keyboard.

**Sometimes it works, but I don't know how it works, I press almost all the keys.**

**My textField code block**

```
    lazy var searchTextField: UITextField = {
        var searchTextField = UITextField()
        searchTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        searchTextField.clipsToBounds = true
        searchTextField.placeholder = "Search"
        searchTextField.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        searchTextField.leftViewMode = .always
        searchTextField.returnKeyType = .go
        searchTextField.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 0))
        return searchTextField
    }()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it works with the Navigation Bar, it is non-functional. I removed the navigation bar and it started working without any problems.